# Whatsapp Share Button is not work, how to fix it?

Tags: html, css, fonts, font-awesome

I use the html code instead of plugins to reduce the burden on the website when opened in the browser. This code works on blogger but not on my website based on cms from wordpress.

```css
<style>.float{
 position:fixed;
 width:60px;
 height:60px;
 bottom:20px;
 left:20px;
 background:green;
 color:#FFF;
 border-radius:50px;
 text-align:center;
  font-size:30px;
 box-shadow: 2px 2px 3px #999;
  z-index:100;
}
.my-float{
 margin-top:16px;
}</style>
```

```html
<a href="https://api.whatsapp.com/send?phone=+xxxxxxxxxx&text=Hai%20Dewi's%20Wedding%20%21." class="float" target="_blank">
<i class="fa fa-whatsapp my-float"></i>
</a>
```

With this code I can only get a button without an awesome font fa fa whatsapp.

you can see the results here  https://www.dewiswedding.com

Please help me to solve this problem..

Answer (score 1):

Because you don't add font-awesome to your website,

Insert to head tag:

https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css

Answer (score 0):

Your site is not loading anything from Font Awesome. It appears you are loading a custom font from IcoMoon so the "fa" class will not do anything.

Either use the whatsapp icon from IcoMoon or load in font awesome either locally or from a CDN

Answer (score 0):

Try this answer I think this one is useful for you.

```css
.float {
 position: fixed;
 width:60px;
 height:60px;
 bottom:20px;
 left:20px;
 background: green;
 color: #ffffff;
 border-radius:50px;
 text-align:center;
  font-size: 30px;
 box-shadow: 0 0 5px rgba(0,0,0,.05), 2px 2px 5px rgba(0,0,0,.1);
}
.my-float {
 margin-top:15px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<a href="https://api.whatsapp.com/send?phone=+xxxxxxxxxx&text=Hai%20Dewi's%20Wedding%20%21." class="float" target="_blank">
<i class="fa fa-whatsapp my-float"></i>
</a>
```